# Why is the area of the sky outside a rainbow darker?

Tags: optics

When trying to broaden my understanding I looked at pictures of rainbows online via google image search and noticed a trend:

The area by the rainbow near the outer red band is darker. Is this an optical illusion?

If I had to guess I think that it’s because the colors we perceive altogether if mixed make black or brown (or some dark mixture of colors) and block some of the light out in the same angled path that made the rainbow.

Just a thot[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phenomenon is called Alexander's band. You can find more on that here [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_band).